# is there an algorithm (+python implementation) for max modularity with constraints?

Tags: python, networking, igraph, networkx, modularity

Given a network `N` - is there an algorithm and implementation for finding the node partition to `k` communities given the desired size of each communities? 
Specifically, let's consider `k=2` and the cluster sizes are `n1` and `n2`.

The exhaustive way is to try all partitions of the network for communities of the respective size. Is there any faster even sampling base algorithm?

Comment: If you're looking for a faster implementation, you need to provide the code for the implementation we should be comparing against.

Comment: If you can formulate this more precisely, with examples, it might work as a question on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Modularity maximization is NP-hard. ([See here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0608255)) There are tons of approximation methods, though. networkx includes the Girvan–Newman algorithm, and igraph includes eight community detection algorithms.